Copy the entire range in VBA (values only)

I'm using the below code to copy certain cells in a worksheet. Now I want to implement the same code to another sheet but the issue is the code only select the cells with values only. instead I want it to select the entire range with data (illustrrated in the image)
New to VB, any help would be much appreciated.
Sub Copy1()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rSel As Range

    Set rng = Range("B8:GS56")
    Set rSel = Nothing

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If rSel Is Nothing Then
                Set rSel = r
            Else
                Set rSel = Union(rSel, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If Not rSel Is Nothing Then rSel.Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Tried a code failed to get expected result

Range("B8:GS56").Copy for example

Side note: in general, you want to avoid using select in your code


Your code is close to finish, you just need to change a code line.

Select is not necessary in most case.


How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
Sub Copy1()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rSel As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("B8:GS56")
    Set rSel = Nothing
    
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If rSel Is Nothing Then
                Set rSel = r
            Else
                Set rSel = Range(rSel, r) ' **
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If Not rSel Is Nothing Then
        rSel.Select
        Selection.Copy
        ' Copy to somewhere
'        rSel.Copy Sheets(2).Range("B100")
    End If
End Sub


Since you're starting in VBA I want to point out sometimes solutions may be a bit fancier than needed. What you have here seems like a combination of a solution you found online but didn't entirely understand what they're doing and recording a macro.
If you want to take a raw range of cells and simply do something to/with that range, you can invoke it directly or variable-ize it then invoke it. If you need to look at a range with logic such as "ignoring blanks copy the cells within this range" that's when you'd want to iterate through them.
Sub Copy1()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("B8:GS56")

    rng.Copy

End Sub

Even better, since you're copying presumably you may be pasting this data somewhere, but you can actually skip the whole process of copy and pasting in vba by saying so, like below. It's easy to think like an excel user, but recognize some steps such as selecting cells, copying data, pasting data, can all be extra unnecessary steps of your project.
Sub Copy2()
'This will copy the data in A1 to cell A2
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = Range("A2")

    rng2 = rng1

End Sub

However, in a case where there's multiple cells your range you'd still want to paste it, but can be treated at once.
Sub Copy3()
'This will copy the data in A1:A2 to cell B2:B3 (even with B3 not said explicitly)
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A1:A2")
    Set rng2 = Range("B2")

    rng1.Copy Destination:=rng2

End Sub


Sub Copy1()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B8:GS56")

rng.Copy

End Sub. this one did not solve my issue as it just selects the entire range within B8:GS56. However, I want to select and copy the range with values. Like B8:D10 (as shown in the image) - Also all the cells run with formula thanks for your answer

@EmreSanli your question is how to copy the range, That's how you copy it. Then, I go on to explain, presuming your goal is to eventually paste this data as well, how you'd doing that, figuring that's what you meant. Try the last solution, or clarify in more detail what isn't working (as in what's happening) and what needs to happen. If you need to maintain formulas or only want values or something else, that's also something you need to explain as it's different.

Copy Values

Here's a common scenario.
You don't want to use Select and any flavors of Active unless necessary.
You can copy values by assignment without using the (slow) Range.Copy method.


Sub CopyValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "B8:GS56"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source 'area' range ('sarg'), the range from the first cell
    ' to the intersection between the last (bottom-most) non-blank row
    ' and the last (right-most) non-blank column of the given range ('srg').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim slcell As Range:
    Set slcell = srg.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    If slcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank in """ & sws.Name & "!" & srg.Address(0, 0) _
             & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = slcell.Row
    
    Set slcell = srg.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Dim slCol As Long: slCol = slcell.Column
    
    Dim sarg As Range:
    Set sarg = sws.Range(srg.Cells(1), sws.Cells(slRow, slCol))
    
    ' Reference the destination range ('drg'), the range starting
    ' with the given cell ('dcell') resized to the same number
    ' of rows and columns of the source 'area' range ('sarg').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = dcell.Resize(sarg.Rows.Count, sarg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy values.
    
    drg.Value = sarg.Value
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Copied values from """ & sws.Name & "!" & sarg.Address(0, 0) _
        & """ to """ & dws.Name & "!" & drg.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


This will copy only the cells within your range area that are populated with constants (i.e. values not formulas) to a specified location on another sheet:
Sub test()    

    ' set-up
    Dim sourcerange As Range, destinationcell As Range
    Dim cells_with_constants As Range, boundary As Range, i As Integer
    
    Set sourcerange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:GS56") 'change Sheet1 if necessary
    Set destinationcell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1") 'change as necessary
    
    'get cells within range that have values
    Set cells_with_constants = sourcerange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
    'find boundary of those cells
    With cells_with_constants
        Set boundary = .Areas(1)
        For i = 2 To .Areas.Count
            Set boundary = Range(boundary, .Areas(i))
        Next
    End With
    
    'copy all cells within boundary
    destinationcell.Resize(boundary.Rows.Count, boundary.Columns.Count).Value = boundary.Value
        
End Sub

